# Spreedsheet (GOOGLE): New Colum with specific code

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make a code that inserts specific information from my spreadsheet.

Right now I have the following code as an example:

```
=B3*0
```

and

```
=Vlookup(AG18;Blad2!A1:O39; 3; True)
```

When I try to add a new column and copy and paste this code it will skip a letter forward. So for example:

If I copy from column AA to AB every code changes from `B3*0` -> `C3*0`.

and

If I copy from column AA to AB every code changes from `=Vlookup(AG18;Blad2!A1:O39; 3; True)` -> `=Vlookup(AG18;Blad2!B1:O39; 3; True)`.

When it happens on the last example the code won't work.

So now I wanna script some code that inserts a total column with every code exactly as it was the column before. So a kind of set information column.

I am using this spreadsheet to calculate my income and its very annoying to have to rewrite half the code everytime I try to add to the spreedsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `$` character to your cell references. You can put it before the column letter and/or before the row number, for example:

```
$B3 * 0
```

or

```
B$3 * 0
```

or

```
$B$3 * 0
```

The `$` means that when you copy/paste or fill down/across the formula, it doesn't increment the column and/or the row number.

For your example, as you're moving the cell across columns, I suspect you will want the `$` sign before the column letter, but the best way to understand it will be to experiment with it.